Excel chart text on Y axis
and @Jon Peltier [tag: Jon Peltier ]
I have an Excel chart that I am trying to put text on its Y-axis. However, since I have four values/text, I cannot use the custom option.
If anyone can help, it would be highly appreciated.
Here is my table of data:
data
the chart/graph
I am trying to put those descriptions on the Y-axis. For example, 1 is an Independent float, 2 is a managed float, etc.
I tried the custom of Y axis, but since I have 4 values, I cannot use that option
I also tried to merge a bar chart with my graph, but didn't work.

So have the text in  a cell on the spreadsheet and link to that from the chart. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/70237879/4961700

Thank you for your reply, but I don't want to have textbox on my chart

So you can link to a cell from the chart labels, even the cart main or axis titles... And, if you read my answer, you would have seen that was mentioned in it.

Did you search? Does this work?

@SolarMike, I cannot figure it out, can you please be more specific? or at least give me an example how it works on a chart.

@Excellor, yes I read that and I tried it but doesn't work on my chart

So check out the method shown in my answer.

This might also be worth exploring. Basically you add a dummy series with data labels which replace the labels on your y-axis. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30300014/how-to-create-a-text-based-y-axis-on-excel-chart BTW what sort of chart  is it? Might be worth adding a screen shot of it.

@TomSharpe, thanks I reviewed that post, it doesn't work on my chart. It is a BW plot, but use this chart for other purposes

So, just to show how to link the chart title to a cell containing text:

select the chart title box so it shows the blue "dots" on the corners,

type "=" in the formula bar and select the cell containing the text required.


Note if the text in the cell is edited, then the chart title will update without needing to edit the chart.

The same works for the axis text as well.

I can replicate what you did. Now let's say we want to change the Y axis and instead, 1, 2, 3, and 4 put text;

So consider laying one chart on top of another, see this for an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53809162/4961700
